# How to host my WCF service in my website?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, hosting

I am new to WCF. I have developed a sample WCF service. My service uses the `basicHttp` binding.

I host my service in local IIS 7.5 using WAS and it works fine. Now I want to host my service in my website.

I search Google but there most of them are hosted in localhost in IIS. Please tell me how to I do that? It will be better to refer some tutorial or step by step guide.

Comment: See: [How to Host a WCF service in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx) - whether that's `localhost` or any other server is totally irrelevant - just follow those steps.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have basically two options, I believe:

**Option 1 - "bin" deploy** (preferred option)

1. compile your WCF service into a DLL (class library)
2. create a website in IIS
3. copy the WCF DLL's into the website's `.\bin` folder
4. create a `*.svc` file in that website
5. add an appropriate `web.config` in the website folder to define your endpoints and service configuration etc.

Your WCF service will now be reachable at the website's base address, plus the name of the `*.svc` file, e.g.

```
http://myserver/someweb/Myservice.svc
```

Your `*.svc` would look something like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="WCF_Simple_Service.HelloIndigoService"  %>
```

The `Service=` attributes denotes the class implementing the service - fully qualified with its namespace.

**Option 2 - put stuff into `App_Code`**

1. create a website in IIS
2. put all your WCF related `*.cs` files directly into the `.\App_Code` folder
3. create a `*.svc` file in that website
4. add an appropriate `web.config` in the website folder to define your endpoints and service configuration etc.

Your WCF service will now be reachable at the website's base address, plus the name of the `*.svc` file, e.g.

```
http://myserver/someweb/Myservice.svc
```

Your `*.svc` would look something like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="Service" 
    CodeBehind="~/App_Code/Service.cs" %>
```

A simple, sample `web.config` might look something like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WithDebug">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <services>
    <service name="SimpleWCF.HelloIndigoService" behaviorConfiguration="WithDebug">
      <endpoint
          address=""
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="SimpleWCF.IHelloIndigoService" />
      <endpoint
          address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

You basically define your `<service>` tag - and again: the `name=` denotes the class implementing the service - fully qualified with its namespace. It must contain at least one endpoint - a "mex" endpoint is optional - but very useful, especially for development and testing. It allows client to "discover" the service and get its service description so it can interface with it.

Once your service is deployed in IIS, you can see it in action using a tool like the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) that ships for free with WCF, or [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) which is a general-purpose SOAP testing utility (with a free edition for you to use).

Comment: Mistake in option 2 behaviorConfiguration="true" correct is behaviorConfiguration="WithDebug"

Comment: @PavelJedlicka: you're absolutely right - thanks for pointing out this mistake - fixed!

Answer (score 3):

old thread, if someone finds it... but instead of your *.svc you can also create in your global.asax:

```
static Global()
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("ExternalServices/SOAP/test", new     ninjectServiceHostFactory(), typeof(testService)));
}
```

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: @mav3n: If you are hosting a website AND want to host a WCF service (in your website) then you can add the code above in the global.asax. That way you don't need to add a seperate *.svc file. You would create a service like you would always do.
In my example I've use Ninject, but obviously you can use the default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Marc's answer, if you add factory attribute to your *.svc file like the one below, you dont need to change ANYTHING in web.config file which is in your main project. Let me repeat it again. no massive mess in web.config file, leave it as is. It’s due to the fact the Factory attribute in the svc file which take care if it all.

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WCF_Simple_Service.HelloIndigoService" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"  %>
```

But I must say that when you call your service, it will give endpoint not found error. But when you call your methods in your service, they will all work. tested in restful wcf.