# Combining ASP.NET interface and WCF service into a single project

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, visual-studio, wcf

This is sort of a weird question. I have two separate Visual Studio projects running in the same solution. One is a WCF service (essentially the server) that interacts with a database, the other is an ASP.NET project running AngularJS that simply provides an interface for interacting with the service. The reason for this is that the two projects obviously run on different ports, and it would be better if they ran on one.

Is it feasible to combine these into a single project? Does that even make sense? Or do the two projects need to remain separate?

Comment: They are separate for  a reason. It makes solution more scalable. Say tomorrow you want to implement another system that requires some data from same database in that case you can reuse the WCF service. Also separating it makes it easy to deploy solution on different servers and share the load. For some reason you need to restart your UI server that will not impact other applications consuming your WCF service.

Comment: @Hakunamatata So... not advisable, but possible? Lol

Comment: It's not advisable but yes it is possible. see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374131/how-to-host-my-wcf-service-in-my-website).

Comment: @vendettamit Thanks, but that answer seems more geared towards putting a WCF service into a website. I'm looking to keep the service and integrate the interface into it. Is there a way for the service's dll to include all of the ASP.NET project's html, javascript, etc files?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's feasible/possible. Asp.net have it's own life cycle to manage a web application. You're asking for wcf to keep asp.net while in reality asp.net manages wcf in IIS hosting. you are thinking it completely opposite way.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368071/call-wcf-service-from-javascript-html-within-service